# How can gravity change the wavelength of a photon without the two peaks or troughs to accelerate one from the other?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light, redshift, gravitational-redshift

How can gravity change the wavelength of a photon without the two peaks or troughs to accelerate one from the other? So is it possible that gravity accelerates light? Can the a certain wavelength emitted far from the sky shorten its wavelength only due to change of speed of the photon when it reaches Earth so even the two peaks are at same distance one from the other they reach the reciever faster so the interval of the two peaks reaching the reciever is shorter so it looks like the frequency increased?

Answer (score 1):

> How can gravity change the wavelength of a photon without the two peaks or troughs to accelerate one from the other? So is it possible that gravity accelerates light?

Yes. In general relativity the acceleration from gravity is coordinate acceleration. In coordinates where there is gravitational acceleration, that acceleration affects light as well as ordinary objects.

Note that, in a coordinate independent sense, movement under gravity is inertial movement in a “straight line”. This coordinate independent sense applies to light also. So the answer of the previous paragraph should be understood as a property of the coordinate system, rather than light.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity field is an area where optical density of space is higher than that of empty space.

Gravity field is an area where refractive index of space is higher than one.

So here is a video about light entering and leaving a gravity field:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0PQNvtetc0

Oh yes, very nice, the video also explains that it is absolutely impossible that frequency of light would change when moving from medium to a different medium.

So now we know what happens to light entering gravity field: Exactly what the video shows.

Now for some reason an observer in a gravity well observes extra high frequency of light coming from above although the frequency does not change.

Well that must have something to do with the observer then, not the light, because the frequency of the light does not change.

Observer is extra young when he gets back up from the optically dense area of space. So yes observer was effected by the gravity.

Answer (score -1):

> How can gravity change the wavelength of a photon without the two peaks or troughs to accelerate one from the other?

There is a basic misunderstanding here. It is classical electromagnetic radiation that has a wavelength, in vacuum connected to frequency by the classical $f=c/λ$. The  photon does not have peaks and troughs because a photon is an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle)  **point** particle of zero mass , $energy=hν$ where $ν$ is the frequency of classical light that  emerges from a synergy of a large number of photons.

[This experiment](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) of "single photon striking double slits" can give an intuition of how quantum mechanically single photons, point particles, add up to classical em radiation.

The peaks and troughs of classical em radiation are collective effects of the way the quantum wavefunctions of the large number of photons adds up to the classical wave . The frequency changes of the classical em radiation are mathematically connected with the changes in the energy of the individual photons that build up the wave, and there are no peaks and troughs in the photon trajectories. The wave nature is in the quantum mechanical probability distribution.